# Reading empty files with scala

Tags: scala, readline

I wrote the following function in scala which reads a file into a list of strings. My aim is to make sure that if the file input is empty that the returned list is empty too. Any idea how to do this in an elegant way:

```
def linesFromFile(file: String): List[String] = {

  def materialize(buffer: BufferedReader): List[String] = materializeReverse(buffer, Nil).reverse

  def materializeReverse(buffer: BufferedReader, accumulator: List[String]): List[String] = {
    buffer.readLine match {
      case null => accumulator
      case line => materializeReverse(buffer, line :: accumulator)
    }
  }

  val buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))
  materialize(buffer)
}
```

Comment: why don''t you do `Source.fromFile(new File(file)).getLines`? thats more elegant I guess

Comment: You can have a look at https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-open-read-text-files-in-scala-cookbook-examples

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work, but it's rather inefficient in memory usage: you read in the entire file into memory, then waste more memory and processing putting the lines in the right order.

Using the `Source.fromFile` method in the standard library is your best bet (which also supports various file encodings), as specified in other comments/answers.

However, if you must roll your own, I think using a `Stream` (a *lazy* form of list) makes more sense than a `List`. You can return each line one at a time, and can terminate the stream when the end of the file is reached. This can be done as follows:

```scala
import java.io.{BufferedReader, FileReader}

def linesFromFile(file: String): Stream[String] = {

  // The value of buffer is available to the following helper function. No need to pass as
  // an argument.
  val buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))

  // Helper: retrieve next line from file. Called only when next value requested.
  def materialize: Stream[String] = {

    // Uncomment to demonstrate non-recursive nature of this method.
    //println("Materialize called!")

    // Read the next line and wrap in an option. This avoids the hated null.
    Option(buffer.readLine) match {

      // If we've seen the end of the file, return an empty stream. We're done reading.
      case None => {
        buffer.close()
        Stream.empty
      }

      // Otherwise, prepend the line read to another call to this helper.
      case Some(line) => line #:: materialize
    }
  }

  // Start the process.
  materialize
}
```

Although it looks like `materialize` is recursive, in fact it is only called when another value needs to be retrieved, so you do not need to worry about stack overflows or recursion. You can verify this by uncommenting the `println` call.

For example (in a *Scala REPL* session):

```scala
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_171).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import java.io.{BufferedReader, FileReader}
import java.io.{BufferedReader, FileReader}

scala> def linesFromFile(file: String): Stream[String] = {
     |
     |   // The value of buffer is available to the following helper function. No need to pass as
     |   // an argument.
     |   val buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))
     |
     |   // Helper: retrieve next line from file. Called only when next value requested.
     |   def materialize: Stream[String] = {
     |
     |     // Uncomment to demonstrate non-recursive nature of this method.
     |     println("Materialize called!")
     |
     |     // Read the next line and wrap in an option. This avoids the hated null.
     |     Option(buffer.readLine) match {
     |
     |       // If we've seen the end of the file, return an empty stream. We're done reading.
     |       case None => {
     |         buffer.close()
     |         Stream.empty
     |       }
     |
     |       // Otherwise, prepend the line read to another call to this helper.
     |       case Some(line) => line #:: materialize
     |     }
     |   }
     |
     |   // Start the process.
     |   materialize
     | }
linesFromFile: (file: String)Stream[String]

scala> val stream = linesFromFile("TestFile.txt")
Materialize called!
stream: Stream[String] = Stream(Line 1, ?)

scala> stream.head
res0: String = Line 1

scala> stream.tail.head
Materialize called!
res1: String = Line 2

scala> stream.tail.head
res2: String = Line 2

scala> stream.foreach(println)
Line 1
Line 2
Materialize called!
Line 3
Materialize called!
Line 4
Materialize called!
```

Note how `materialize` is only called when we attempt to read another line from the file. Furthermore, it is not called if we've already retrieved a line (for example, both `Line 1` and `Line 2` in the output are only preceded by `Materialize called!` when first referenced).

To your point about empty files, in this case, an empty stream is returned:

```scala
scala> val empty = linesFromFile("EmptyFile.txt")
Materialize called!
empty: Stream[String] = Stream()

scala> empty.isEmpty
res3: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "empty" you mean contains absolutely nothing, your aim is already attained.

If however you meant "contains only whitespaces", you can filter out lines containing only whitespaces from your final list by modifying `materializeReverse`.

```
def materializeReverse(buffer: BufferedReader, accumulator: List[String]): List[String] = {
    buffer.readLine match {
        case null => accumulator
        case line if line.trim.isEmpty => materializeReverse(buffer, accumulator)
        case line => materializeReverse(buffer, line :: accumulator)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method

```
val result = Source.fromFile("C:\\Users\\1.txt").getLines.toList
```

Hope that helps. Please ask if you need any further clarification.